# How can I hide my api keys when deploying an app in a virtual machine on the cloud?

Tags: javascript, api, digital-ocean

We are deploying our app in DigitalOcean and in order for our app to work we have a .env file which we fill with api secret keys for stuff like stripe, auth0, aws etc... I dont feel like this is safe enough though because many people have access to the virtual machine and can view those api keys. What is the best way to secure them ?

Comment: Instead of an `.env` file you can just use [their dashboard](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/how-to/use-environment-variables/) to set Environment Variables. Of course people with admin privileges can still view those.

Comment: Huh thats a nice way too. At least we will restrict the enviroment vars to only the Admins. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If people you do not trust have admin access to the machine, then you can not trust the machine with secrets.

Use a different machine which only trusted people have admin access to.

Comment: Hmm. Yeah I guess you are right. I was just wondering if this is how it is done for real.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some kind of secret manager like https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/create-secret-quickstart.

You can track the access of the assets and give or remove access.